# xmpp - ping pong

Tags: xmpp

So in order to know if there's still an active data connection, I'm sending a ping every like 5 minute interval, and waiting for the server to respond.  So basically, I'm using the iq id as a key on this pinging method.  I'll send a ping, and store the iq id, and i'll say assume that noDataConnection = true.  Now, if I receive a pong with the same iq id, I assume that the connection is alive, so I'll set noDataConnection = false.  However, if there's no data connection, i'll continue to send pings setting noDataConnection = true, and never receiving any so it will remain true unless it recovers and obtained a data connection.

Excerpt from http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0199.html#s2c:
PING:

```
<iq from='juliet@capulet.lit/balcony' to='capulet.lit' id='c2s1' type='get'>
  <ping xmlns='urn:xmpp:ping'/>
</iq>
```

PONG:

```
<iq from='capulet.lit' to='juliet@capulet.lit/balcony' id='c2s1' type='result'/>
```

My only concern about this, is what if I received an iq that isn't a result of my ping and my application will assume that noDataConnection = true, since the iq id that it receives doesn't match up to my ping iq id that is sent.  Is there a way to know if the iq that I received is a result of my ping?

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure if I can follow you: If the `iq result` type has the same `id` as the `get` type, then you have received a pong. Other `iq result` types should come with different `id`'s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is to prefix the iq id that i've sent with a text "ping", so basically if i received an iq prefix with "ping", then it is the pong of my ping.